# терминал не видит composer

Tags: php, composer

C:\xampp\htdocs\work\functions\social\laravel>composer dump-autoload -o
"composer" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Композер не установлен. Установите его глобально. На официальном сайте все есть

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно или указать полный путь к **composer.phar** для интерпретатора php

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\work\functions\social\laravel>php <путь к composer.phar> dump-autoload -o
```

или добавить в PATH путь к **composer.phar** и **composer.bat**. [Документация по установке composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation).